# Is my understanding of Penrose's singularity theorem correct?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, singularities, geodesics

My understanding of Penrose's singularity theorem and the background to it is as follows:

After it was proven that the singularity at the event horizon of a black hole was a coordinate artifact, physicists were still sceptical that a black hole would ever form in the first place. This was because of the assumptions that a black hole formed from a perfectly spherical ball of matter which would not occur in nature.

The idea was that something would happen to prevent a singularity at the centre of the black hole in the rough non-spherical world we live in, such as an explosion etc. However, Penrose demonstrated that given specific mass-energy conditions, general relativity predicts geodesic incompleteness and thus singularities irrespective of the geometry of the mass-energy. This means that that particular challenge to the idea of black holes was void and, assuming the conditions were met, singularities were inevitable.

This is a very rough summary but does it capture the theorem and the motivation behind it adequately? Does this mean that the only way to avoid singularities in general relativity is to assume general relativity is an approximation rather than a complete theory (hence quantum gravity)?

Comment: I can't answer the question about the historical motive, but for checking your understanding of the theorem itself, Witten's *Light Rays, Singularities, and All That* ([arXiv:1901.03928](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03928)) is a great resource for anyone familiar with the basics of general relativity. And by the way, for realistic black holes, the mass inflation instability is an important part of the singularity story. For more detail about that, see Poisson (1990), [A look inside black holes](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1990JRASC..84..191P).

Comment: This seems like a good summary of the motivation behind Penrose's result. Do note that in the Newtonian case, a large enough sphere of gas will undergo collapse to a point of diverging density, this is called Jeans Instability. In this case it was known that the diverging density was an artifact of symmetry and was not present in general circumstances.

Comment: Quantum gravity cannot remove singularities, exactly because of the Penrose theorem - if the conditions are met, then it makes no difference what theory you use, classical or quantum.